# Deploying a Service fabric app from Team Services to Azure

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I need some help with deploying a Service fabric app from Team Services to Azure.

I’m getting the following error from the Agent in Team Services (see screenshot below):

> 2018-06-22T13:17:13.3007613Z ##[error] An error occurred attempting to
>   import the certificate. Ensure that your service endpoint is
>   configured properly with a correct certificate value and, if the
>   certificate is password-protected, a valid password.
>
> Error message: Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s):
>   "Cannot find the requested object.

Please advise.

[image: TS Deploy error]

Here is my Service Fabric Security security page, don't remember where I set up the password needed on the VSTS side but I took note of it and believe it's correct.
[image: SF Security]

Here is the Endpoint page on the VSTS side:
[image]

Comment: Have you referenced to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-app-with-cicd-vsts)? You could get the detail steps about how to deploy a service fabric from VSTS.

Comment: Went through that tutorial and several other more. I need some help specific to the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved with the help of MS Support by **creating a new Certificate in the Key Vault and Adding it to the Service Fabric**, steps:

**Azure Portal**:

- Home > Key vaults > YourKeyVault - Certificates: Generate/Import
  Generate new key with a CertificateName of your choosing and CN=CertificateName as Subject.
- Home > Key vaults > YourKeyVault - Certificates > CertificateName
  Select the only version available and Download in PFX/PEM format.
- Power Shell: Convert to Base64 string, CertificateBase64
  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("c:\YourCertificate.pfx"))
- Home > YourServicefabric - Security: Add
  Add the Certificate you created as Admin Client by providing 's thumbprint.

**VSTS/TFS**:

- Build and release > Your pipeline: Edit
  In the Deployment Process Service Fabric Environment click Manage for Cluster Connection and add a new connection. Besides the other information, in the Client Certificate paste the previous CertificateBase64.

Comment: That convert-to-base64 tip is the key still, Really should be more prominently placed other than a info tooltip. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Service Endpoint in VSTS:

- Whether it has a properly base64 encoded certificate, with a private key.
- Also, check if the provided passphrase is correct.
- Also, check if the service endpoint is configured as `tcp://mycluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com:19000`.
- Check if the thumbprint is correct.

Comment: Added additional details to the original question. Not sure how to check the base64 part. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: In the endpoint configuration dialog, click on the 'i' next to the textbox, and it'll display a message about how to create a base64 string from your pfx

Comment: Thank you for this. Any idea how to get the pfx file. Look at the screnshot in the original post, from Azure Portal, does not show an option to download it.